# Convert `oauth_token` to `access_token` in LinkedIn OAuth 2 API

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, access-token, linkedin-api

How can a user convert a `oauth_token` (a short lived token) that is generated from the JavaScript SDK to a `access_token` (long lived token). I do not see any such information in the documentation, so not sure how to do that. I can see that I can use this `oauth_token` for accessing LinkedIn services, but to use it for a longer period , I would like to convert that to a long lived `access_token`.

I have seen the REST API's flow, but that does not seem to be helpful to what I was looking for.

Any help would be grateful.

Comment: Please provide some code you are using and describe what an "oauth_token" you are referring to. Have you looked at: https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/oauth2#

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I was referring to the oauth_token generated using JavaScript SDK. https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/getting-started-js-sdk.   If you use LinkedIN javascript API's, then it is generated using "IN.ENV.auth.oauth_token"

Comment: I'm having this issue as well - in my case even just being able to use that oauth token to make a request immediately would be enough.  You mention in your comment that is possible - do you have an example request showing how?